# Undefined Reference to function while threading in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix, undefined-reference

I looked up the other questions to make sure this isn't duplicate.

I have 3 files:

```
file1.h
file1.c
file2.c
```

file1.h has this line in it:

```
void *myFunction(void *vargp);
```

file1.c has:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "file1.h"    
void *myFunction(void *vargp)
    { 
        //do stuff
        return 0;
    }
```

file2.c has:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "file1.h"

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int t1; 
    t1 =  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myFunction, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following command to compile and link:

```
gcc -pthread -o file2 file2.c
```

and I get these errors:

```
file2.c:(.text+0xa64): undefined reference to `myFunction'
file2.c:(.text+0xa68): undefined reference to `myFunction'
```

Comment: You're compiling `myCode.c` but reference `file1.c`, `file2.c`, and then mention `file3.c` .... are you sure you're using the right files for everything?

Comment: @txtechhelp ya sorry fixed that

Comment: What happens when you run `gcc -pthread -o myCode file1.c file2.c` ?

Comment: @txtechhelp same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two independent solutions that both worked:

1. doing this: `gcc -pthread -o file2 file2.c file1.c`
2. doing this: putting `#include "file1.c"` in code file2.c instead of `#include "file1.h"`

Edit: You can't do method #2 if you have two mains!

Answer (score 0):

i defined my thread function below thread creation then it works fine